# OTP autofilling not working - facebook account kit

Tags: android, facebook, account-kit

I'm using the following link to integrate facebook account kit `(version 5.0.0)` to my `android` app. I'm using both the sms and whatsapp logins but the received codes are not being autofilled in both the cases:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/

What could be the possible cause of this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autofill feature has been removed in their latest sdk. Reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/704794763310779/
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/615262038994308/